# Query Performance Issue With Oracle View

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join

This may be difficult to understand (as I must be vague for security reasons), but I will attempt to explain my dilemma.

I have two tables SD, and SS.

SD has a 1 to many relationship with SS on the OL_ID column.

I am creating a view with SD and SS that returns the SD.SD_ID value only if the SD record has no child SS records associated, else it returns the SS.SS_ID (Creating a materialied view is not an option).

When I create the view, the assumption is that the NVL statement in the beginning is causing a full table scan, therefore making the view perform very slowly. I've modified the NVL statement to return a hard coded number instead of the SD.SD_ID from a record and the query time dropped tremendously.

The tables have already been indexed. I have not put on a function based index and am unsure if it would even be useful in this situation.

Basically, I am wondering if I can rewrite this query in such a way that the NVL either:

1. can be removed but the goal can still be reached
2. the NVL can be optimized so the query time can be decreased.

I will try to answer any questions I can, but the information I can provide may be limited. Any rewrite ideas would be appreciated. Efficiency is not necessarily the goal, more rewriting to bypass the "NVL" statement in the beginning.

**CODE**

```
CREATE VIEW SD_VIEW(S_ID, S_OL_ID) AS    
select NVL(SS.SD_id, SD.SS_id) S_ID, SD.OL_ID S_OL_ID
from sd
left join SS
on sd.OL_ID = SS.OL_ID
;
```

Comment: You could replace this with a `union all`.  One side selects the `sd.ss_id` where there is no matching row and one side selects the `ss.sd_id` where there is a match.

Comment: @JustinCave THANK YOU! That was very helpful!!

Comment: Why would you think that the NVL() in the select list is a (performance) problem?